# Launch4j doesn't work (main class not found)

Tags: java, launch4j

I am using Launch4j to create an setup file. I have 7 classes, under a package. And JavaSamp is my main class. I have created jar files for all the classes. And my launch4j looks like this:

```
 <launch4jConfig>
  <dontWrapJar>true</dontWrapJar>
  <headerType>gui</headerType>
  <jar></jar>
  <outfile>install\Piratechx.exe</outfile>
  <errTitle></errTitle>
  <cmdLine></cmdLine>
  <chdir>.</chdir>
  <priority>normal</priority>
  <downloadUrl>http://java.com/download</downloadUrl>
  <supportUrl></supportUrl>
  <customProcName>true</customProcName>
  <stayAlive>false</stayAlive>
  <manifest></manifest>
  <icon></icon>
  <classPath>
    <mainClass>JavaSamp</mainClass>
    <cp>lib/JavaSamp.jar</cp>
    <cp>lib/DataBaseHelper.jar</cp>
    <cp>lib/JavaDemo.jar</cp>
    <cp>lib/FileEncryption.jar</cp>
    <cp>lib/SendEmail.jar</cp>
    <cp>lib/WriterHelper</cp>
  </classPath>
  <jre>
    <path>jre6</path>
    <minVersion></minVersion>
    <maxVersion></maxVersion>
    <jdkPreference>jreOnly</jdkPreference>
  </jre>
  <versionInfo>
    <fileVersion>1.0.0.0</fileVersion>
    <txtFileVersion>1.0</txtFileVersion>
    <fileDescription>Piratechx</fileDescription>
    <copyright>Copyright (c) 2007 FSP</copyright>
    <productVersion>1.0.0.0</productVersion>
    <txtProductVersion>1.0</txtProductVersion>
    <productName>Piratechx</productName>
    <companyName>FSP</companyName>
    <internalName>Piratechx</internalName>
    <originalFilename>Piratechx.exe</originalFilename>
  </versionInfo>
 </launch4jConfig>
```

Any suggestion pls...

Comment: Couldnot find the main class:JavaSamp

Comment: I am getting the same error on Vista x86, but not on some other OS'es.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't just define JavaSamp as main class. If it is in a seperate namespace or something (which it probably is considering you are using multiple jars) you would need to declare the full 'proper' name

Comment: Do u mean the full path of JavaSamp, ie., com.demo.test.Java
Samp

Comment: Still I have the same error as Couldnot find the main class:com.test.demo.JavaSamp